# Webpack path problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I started to study webpack and came across a problem

**Project structure**

```
webpack-project/
|-- frontend/
|    |-- index.html
|    |-- main.js
|
|-- src/
|    |-- images/
|    |   |-- img.jpg
|    |
|    |-- menu/
|    |   |-- style.css
|    |
|    |-- home.js
|    |-- variable.js
|
|-- webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config**

```
let autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: './home.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/frontend',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ["env"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']})]
};
```

When running webpack with `context: __dirname + '/src'`  an error is indicated

```
ERROR in ./menu/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js in C:\Users\Admin\Websto
rmProjects\webpack-project/src\menu
 @ ./menu/style.scss 4:14-167

ERROR in ./menu/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js in C:\Users\Artem\
WebstormProjects\webpack-project/src\menu
 @ ./menu/style.scss 7:13-71
```

When using `entry` instead of context: `'./src/home.js'`

But images paths become absolute `frontend/src/images/`, instead of `frontend/images/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided my problem.

After many hours of searching, I looked in the official documentation :/

http://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#windows-paths